# std::shared_ptr and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

I am having some problems with automatic typecasting between `shared_ptr` of inherited classes.

My class structure is as follows, a base class `Base` and two derived classes `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

```
// Base class
class Base {
protected:
  ...
  ...
public:
  Base() = default;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void run() = 0;
  ...
  ...
};

// Derived class
class Derived1: Base {
protected:
  ...
  ...
public:
  Derived1() = default;
  virtual ~Derived1() = default;
  void run() {...}
  ...
  ...
};

// Derived class
class Derived2: Base {
protected:
  ...
  ...
public:
  Derived2() = default;
  virtual ~Derived2() = default;
  void run() {...}
  ...
  ...
};
```

I have a function `doSomething()`

```
void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr) {
  ptr->run();
  ...
}
```

I call the function with the derived classes like so -

```
doSomething(make_shared<Derived1>())
doSomething(make_shared<Derived2>())
```

But I get an error saying -

```
no viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<class Derived1>' to 'shared_ptr<class Base>'
no viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<class Derived1>' to 'shared_ptr<class Base>'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it safe just to use `static_pointer_cast` to the Base type? Like -

```
doSomething(static_pointer_cast<Base>(make_sahred<Derived2>()))
```

***SOLUTION***
My bad... The problem was that I was inheriting the base class privately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the code that you've presented compiles fine: http://ideone.com/06RB2W

```
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
        Base() = default;
        virtual ~Base() = default;
        virtual void run() = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base {
    public:
        Derived1() = default;
        virtual ~Derived1() = default;
        void run() {}
};

class Derived2: public Base {
    public:
        Derived2() = default;
        virtual ~Derived2() = default;
        void run() {}
};

void doSomething(std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr) {
    ptr->run();
}

int main() {
    doSomething(std::make_shared<Derived1>());
    doSomething(std::make_shared<Derived2>());
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad... I was inheriting the class privately in my code! That was a really rookie mistake!

Comment: Does shared_ptr automatically (without any type-casting) converts to base class shared_ptr? Do they share same reference count?

Comment: It does not automatically type cast, but if you manually cast it, then the reference count is shared.

Comment: In your code you didn't manually type cast, so are they sharing the reference count?